# vaadin 7 - move data between sub windows

Tags: vaadin

I have the main UI class with a button that shows a subwindow when clicked.  That subwindow has a textField and a button.  When you press the subwindow's button, another sub window opens.  You could call it the sub-sub window.  This sub-sub window has a textfield and a button that will close this sub-sub window.  I would like to update the textfield in the subwindow when i close this sub-sub window with the textfield value on the sub-sub window.  is there a way to do this without creating everything on the main UI Class?  I would like to create 2 classes for these sub windows and would like to pass the data back. I got it to work by putting everything on the main UI class but i thought there would be a better way.

TIA,

Thomas Kim

Comment: Could you describe your problem with some code samples? I don't see the issue right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either bind all your components which acces shared data to same model, using [Vaadin Data Binding](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/datamodel.html) or you can use [Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364610/vaadin-7-fire-custom-events-between-components) to propagate value changes from subwindows to whichever component may be concerned.

Consider using Model View Presenter pattern to structure you view layer. There is a nice article to explain basics of MVP and its implementation in Vaadin.

> https://vaadin.com/web/magi/home/-/blogs/model-view-presenter-pattern-with-vaadin

This approach will not only solve your problem, but also lead to better separated and maintable presentation layer.