# OptionGroup addValueChangeListener CheckBox

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Vaadin 7.6.5. 
I am trying to figure out why a value change listener fails in the below case?
The CheckBox is observing for addValueChangeListener OptionGroup.

```
@Theme("vaadindemo")
public class VaadindemoUI extends UI {

    @WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = VaadindemoUI.class)
    public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        layout.setMargin(true);
        setContent(layout);

        OptionGroup group = new OptionGroup();
        group.addItem("01");
        group.setItemCaption("01", "ONE");

        group.addItem("02");
        group.setItemCaption("02", "TWO");

        group.addItem("03");
        group.setItemCaption("03", "THREE");
        group.addValueChangeListener(new ValueChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
                System.out.println("group getValue " + event.getProperty().getValue());
                System.out.println("group getType " + event.getProperty().getType());
            }
        });
        CheckBox box = new CheckBox();
        box.setCaption("Check Me");
        //Notify CheckBox of value change of radio button

        //group.addValueChangeListener(box); -- // Code Fails 
        //box.addValueChangeListener(group); // Selected Radio Button is removed  


        TextField field = new TextField();
        field.addValueChangeListener(new ValueChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
                System.out.println("field getValue " + event.getProperty().getValue());
                System.out.println("field getType " + event.getProperty().getType());

                System.out.println("field getType " + field.getValue());
            }
        });


        group.addValueChangeListener(field);// The value is reflected. How do i get only the event without over writing the value

        //group.addValueChangeListener(box);

        layout.addComponent(group);
        layout.addComponent(box);
        layout.addComponent(field);

        Button button = new Button("Click Me");
        button.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                layout.addComponent(new Label("Thank you for clicking"));
            }
        });
        layout.addComponent(button);
    }

}
```

It logs:

```
com.vaadin.data.util.converter.Converter$ConversionException: Unable to convert value of type java.lang.String to presentation type class java.lang.Boolean. No converter is set and the types are not compatible.
    at com.vaadin.data.util.converter.ConverterUtil.convertFromModel(ConverterUtil.java:116)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField.convertFromModel(AbstractField.java:736)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField.convertFromModel(AbstractField.java:721)
    at ...
```

Comment: I would like to know what you are you trying to achieve with that binding? Binding a OptionGroup and a CheckBox is not possible that way as you can see.

Comment: Hi Henri, I looking at the Observer pattern. I need all components in a form to be looking for value change of OptionGroup. The Value change of the OptionGroup should trigger other components to update their states.  The addValueChangeListener works for  TextBox. I am not sure why the value attribute is trying to mapped to CheckBox (boolean) since the CheckBox is only interested to receive the event.

Comment: In Place of the CheckBox , i added a TextField. When I click on the CheckBox  the value of CheckBox is shown in the TextField.   What I am looking for is the event and not interested in the value.

Comment: Then you just add a ValueChangeListener like suggested in an answer.

Comment: Even if i add the addValueChangeListener , the values are propagated to the component and I am only interested in the Event and not the value. Or u referring to using a Custom ValueChangeListener?

Comment: In the answer below , group addValueChangeListener refers to the box element.  I do not want group to decided what happens to the component , i want the group to fireEvent which the observable can received and decided what is to be done.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364610/vaadin-7-fire-custom-events-between-components

Comment: Its Similar to what i want to do. But I wanted to see if I can work within the core framework of vaadin.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like...

```
    group.addValueChangeListener(new ValueChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {

                //Do something with box here? e.g...
                box.setValue(!box.getValue());

            }
        });
```

rather than...

```
group.addValueChangeListener(box);
```

Comment: I do not know before hand how many form elements will be there in the screen. Hence all components in the screen observer the group.AbstractField addValueChangeListener calls-- > AbstractClientConnector addListener(AbstractField.ValueChangeEvent.class, listener,
                VALUE_CHANGE_METHOD);

Comment: AbstractClientConnector addListener(AbstractField.ValueChangeEvent.class, listener,
                VALUE_CHANGE_METHOD);  JavaDoc
Registers a new listener with the specified activation method to listen
events generated by this component. If the activation method does not
have any arguments the event object will not be passed to it when it's
called.

Comment: To clarify, you are saying that you don't know how many components are going to be in your option group?

Comment: I will not know how many UI components (text box, checkbox etc) will be there in the Form. No issue with Items of the Option Group.